# ReadOnly attribute in UWP

Tags: uwp

I couldn't find the `ReadOnly` attribute in UWP. I can set the `ReadOnly` attribute in WPF like below,

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public double? Salary
{
    get
    {
        return _salary;
    }
    set
    {
        _salary = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Salary");
    }
}
```

Is `ReadOnly` attribute is not supported in UWP?

Answer (score 12):

You could make the setter private:

```
public double? Salary
{
    get { return _salary; }
    private set
    {
        _salary = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Salary");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`System.ComponentModel.ReadOnlyAttribute` is not supported in UWP. UWP is targeting .NET Core while WPF targeting .NET Framework.

> .NET for UWP apps does not include all the members of each type.

For all the types under namespace `System.ComponentModel` that are supported in .Net for UWP you can refer to [System.ComponentModel namespaces for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185499.aspx).

From the Version Info section of [ReadOnlyAttribute Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.readonlyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). It is also not available in Windows Universal Platform.